# How to save as picture?

Tags: c#, image, picturebox

I just created a simple webpage in which there is a PictureBox inside a Panel, the PictureBox allow users to import picture, and the Panel allow the user to insert color, so how can i export / save it as .jpeg file?

Comment: picturebox.Image.Save("image.jpg");

Comment: Is this for Winforms, Wpf or ?

Answer (score 4):

```
pictureBox1.Image.Save(filePath, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
```

Check [this MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9t4syfhh.aspx) reference for further knowledge.

Answer (score 1):

> Here is my solution with additional support to various file types:

```
 public void ExportToBmp(string path)
        {
            using(var bitmap = new Bitmap(pictureBox.Width, pictureBox.Height))
            {
            pictureBox.DrawToBitmap(bitmap, pictureBox.ClientRectangle);
            ImageFormat imageFormat = null;

            var extension = Path.GetExtension(path);
            switch (extension)
            {
                case ".bmp":
                    imageFormat = ImageFormat.Bmp;
                    break;
                case ".png":
                    imageFormat = ImageFormat.Png;
                    break;
                case ".jpeg":
                case ".jpg":
                    imageFormat = ImageFormat.Jpeg;
                    break;
                case ".gif":
                    imageFormat = ImageFormat.Gif;
                    break;
                default:
                    throw new NotSupportedException("File extension is not supported");
            }

            bitmap.Save(path, imageFormat);
            }
        }
```