# how to save a modified image to your hard drive?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am fetching an image from the database and displaying it on an image control.I want to save this image to my hard drive  after performing certain annotations on it. How to go about it?

Comment: What do you mean by "performing certain annotations"? Do you want to manipulate the image? And where exactly are you stuck? Please show your code.

Comment: `Image.Save(filepath);`

Comment: Please elaborate more what exacly you are asking. Are you rendering the image on the server, showing it on the cleint side and want to save it (from the browser) on the client side?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to save as picture?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14392261/how-to-save-as-picture)

Comment: pictureBox1.Image.Save(filePath, ImageFormat.Jpeg);

Comment: Simply give it your HDD path or show me your code.

Comment: @Anita Mathew:: Welcome to StackOverflow  , You need to elaborate more about ur problem by adding respected code, so one can understand it better and reply to ur query

Answer (score 0):

`pictureBox1.Image.Save(filePath, ImageFormat.Jpeg);`

Answer (score 0):

While saving, stream the image to bytearray and then save it in your DB. Stream back the bytearray from DB to show the image in Image control. [Here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/21208/Store-or-Save-images-in-SQL-Server) is the Example